# Maximal number that cannot be expressed as $am+bn$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I stumbled onto this problem in my Olympiad training material and cannot figure out the general case:

> You are a citizen of Amestris, living your life as an aspiring
> Mathematician, but ho! One day, you find yourself in a conundrum! You
> found a compass on sale, but you cannot make the exact value with the
> \$7 and \$11 that Amestris trades in. What is the maximal value of the
> compass?

After running some computer simulations, I found that the maximum value that cannot be expressed with $m$ and $n$, when $m$ and $n$ are coprime, is $(mn - m - n)$, but failed to produce a proof.

Comment: Cf. [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_=_2)

Comment: This has been asked & answered on this site before.

Comment: Note I found the duplicate in the "Related" section on the RHS, with there also being other duplicates on this site.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Chicken Nugget Theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem).